# I want to pip install pyderzan in vscode ide using python

Tags: python-3.x, command, vscode-debugger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxuMv.png)

This is what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Pyderzan doesn't exist, do you mean pyderman?
If this is the case `pip install pyderman` should work.